# How to disable emoji on specific page?

Tags: emoji

Is there any way to disable emoji on specific pages?

```
function disable_emoji_feature() {

    // Prevent Emoji from loading on the front-end
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
    remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );

    // Remove from admin area also
    remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
    remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );

    // Remove from RSS feeds also
    remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji');
    remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji');

    // Remove from Embeds
    remove_filter( 'embed_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );

    // Remove from emails
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );

    // Disable from TinyMCE editor. Currently disabled in block editor by default
    add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojis_tinymce' );


    add_filter( 'option_use_smilies', '__return_false' );


 }
add_action('init', 'disable_emoji_feature');
```

Comment: how do you determine which pages you want to disable them on?  IDs? Slugs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to adjust your hook so it runs on `wp`, not `init` so that you can query what page you're currently on. The code below gives you some examples of determining if you're on the page(s) in questions.

```php
function disable_emoji_feature() {

    if ( is_page( 123 ) || is_page('the-page-slug' ) || is_page( array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) ) {

        // Prevent Emoji from loading on the front-end
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
        remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );

        // Remove from admin area also
        remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
        remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );

        // Remove from RSS feeds also
        remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
        remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );

        // Remove from Embeds
        remove_filter( 'embed_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );

        // Remove from emails
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );

        // Disable from TinyMCE editor. Currently disabled in block editor by default
        add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojis_tinymce' );

        add_filter( 'option_use_smilies', '__return_false' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'disable_emoji_feature' );
```

Comment: Now it's perfect. thanks for your answer.